# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) Angular API call

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am receiving an unsupported media type error when attempting to call an API GET call.

Here is the back-end code:

```
    public async Task<JObject> GetSummonerData(GetSummonerDataDto getMatch)
    {
        string username = getMatch.Username;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        string url="https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" +username;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Riot-Token", _riotToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(body);
        return json;
    }
```

Here is the Angular portion:

```
  GetSummonerData(model: any) {
      console.log(model);
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
      return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'getsummonerdata', model);
  }
```

Now when I make this specific call I immediately receive the HTTP 415 error. However, I have another GET function, this functionality is essentially calling `GetSummonerData` back-end multiple times and is WORKING

```
  getSummonerDataMultiple() {
       return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'getsummonerdatamultiple');
```

Here is the back-end code for the above Angular code:

```
    public async Task<JArray> GetSummonerDataMultiple()
    {
        string[] players = {"twokdavey", "jimlan", "captainwalrus69", "pynkcoffee"};
        JArray SummonersData= new JArray();
        foreach(var player in players)
        {
            var user = await GetSummonerData(new GetSummonerDataDto{Username = player});
            if(user != null){
                SummonersData.Add(user);
            }
        }
        return SummonersData;        
    }
```

Please note the only difference is I do not have a DTO (no parameter) in this. `GetSummonerDataDto` is just a simple class that has

```
public string Username {get; set;}
```

and I even hardcoded my parameter to be `{'username': 'tankthebeast'}` for my Angular portion. I have been successful with other functions that involved DTO's, but as much as I go back to the code I do not see any differences. Previous questions to this suggest adding `Content-Type` HTTP header as described on my first Angular portion, yet the error consists.

The biggest glare to my issue is my header is displaying `application/problem+jso`n in the browser, I cannot find more information.

Final piece of information. *Postman* displays all functionality. this is an angular issue that I cannot solve on my part.

Comment: Is your API support JSON?

Comment: @jess yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: **Don't send `Content-Type` HTTP header when using HTTP GET**.

The `Content-Type` HTTP header informs the server about body of the request. In case of HTTP GET you have no body!

More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).